# Failed assertion: line 99 pos 16: 'assetName.isNotEmpty': is not true

Tags: android, flutter, pdf, mobile

I want to pass the parameter link from my reusable handbookoption widget to the pdf viewer class. tried passing the widget but returns assetName.isNotEmpty. also tried  widget.link  but same error. It is a stateful widget also

reusable widget

```
class HandbookOptions extends StatefulWidget {
  final String link;
  late String label;
  late String description;
  late String source;
HandbookOptions({super.key, required this.source,required this.label,required this.description, required this.link});
  State<HandbookOptions> createState() => _HandbookOptionsState();
  }
class _HandbookOptionsState extends State<HandbookOptions>{
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    print(widget.link);
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width; //width of the  screen
    double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height; // height of the screen
    return SizedBox(
      height: 80,
      child: Card(
        color: Colors.black,
        clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12)
          ),
        child: Stack(
          alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
          children: [
            Ink(
              height: 200,
              child: InkWell(
                onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(
                  widget.source,
                  arguments: 'Text from homepage',
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding:  const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
              child: Text(widget.label,
                style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 25),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 45),
              child: Text(widget.description,
                style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 15),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

handbook options
this is where to choose which pdf file to view

````
class Handbook extends StatefulWidget {
  const Handbook({super.key});
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _HandbookState();
}

class _HandbookState extends State<Handbook> {

  String headline = "";
  String type = "";
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }
  
  @override

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width; ///width of screen
  double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;///height of screen
  final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!;
  final uid = user.uid;
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () => FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus(),
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(31, 146, 144, 144),
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Handbook'),
          leading: IconButton(onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(), icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_circle_left_outlined, color: Colors.white,)),
          centerTitle: true,
          backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        ),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, right: 20, top: height * 0.24),
            child: Column(
              children: [
              HandbookOptions(link: 'assets/pdf/Regnum_Dei.pdf', source: '/pdf', label: 'Regnum Dei', description: 'Anthem and Map'),
              const SizedBox(height: 10,),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

}```


//pdf viewer class

class PDFViewer extends StatefulWidget {
  final String link;
  const PDFViewer({super.key, required this.link});
  @override
  // ignore: library_private_types_in_public_api
  _PDFViewerState createState() => _PDFViewerState();
}

class _PDFViewerState extends State<PDFViewer> {
  late PdfViewerController _pdfViewerController;
  final GlobalKey<SfPdfViewerState> _pdfViewerStateKey = GlobalKey();
  @override
  void initState() {
    _pdfViewerController = PdfViewerController();
    super.initState();
    print(widget.link);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
      body: SfPdfViewer.asset(
          widget.link,
          pageLayoutMode: PdfPageLayoutMode.single,
          controller: _pdfViewerController,
          key: _pdfViewerStateKey),
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                _pdfViewerStateKey.currentState!.openBookmarkView();
              },
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.bookmark,
                color: Colors.white,
              )),
          IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                _pdfViewerController.jumpToPage(5);
              },
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.arrow_drop_down_circle,
                color: Colors.white,
              )),
          IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                _pdfViewerController.zoomLevel = 1.25;
              },
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.zoom_in,
                color: Colors.white,
              ))
        ],
      ),
    ));
  }
} 

the error
[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/S01H2.png
````

Comment: widget.link does not work

Comment: solved it by using material page route